# RESTFUL API delete design using mysql

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I suppose the standard delete API would be like this

DELETE example.com/student/:id

But I'm confused with mysql.

I have 2 tables, one is students, one is subjects. The tables look like this

```
students
- id (FK)
- name

subjects
- student_id (PK)
- math
- english
```

so how would I build my REST API? I have to delete in both place, firstly the student and using the same id too, delete his subjects, correct? so I have to 2 query here.

Comment: Yes, your domain model is stored in two tables, so you need to make the deletion in both places. Is this is so surpising?

Comment: @RobertMoskal I'm just confused why when I delete a subject, the student is gone, but not the other way round, when I delete student, I have to delete subject manually.

Comment: 1: I think you swapped `FK` (**F**oreign **K**ey) and `PK` (**P**rimary **K**ey) in your tables description. 2: You'd have to first remove the foreign key, not the primary key (assuming no cascade-ish is set).

Comment: You should post some code and your database ddl.

Comment: @FirstOne if I swap it make sense for restapi, but is the table design correct in the first place?

Comment: @RobertMoskal I already mentioned about my table design, it's just 2 table, I have to get the design right first.

Comment: @GlobinHughes No, I mean, I was talking about `(FK)` and `(PK)` in front of the columns. You swapped them. A foreign key is a _reference_ to a column in another table, so to speak. In your tables, the reference is inside `subjects`, so that's the foreign key (it should read `FK`). Note that I'm not saying this design is good nor bad, I'm just mentioning the terminology.

Comment: I don't know much about the rules to the project, but it seems like a bad design to me. You have two subjects in different columns. What if you need another subject in the future? You should look for database normalization. But as a quick hint..

Comment: Store the subjects as rows (change to a column such as `name` to store it's name). And then I'd say you need another table. This seems like a N-N relation to me: one student can have multiple subjects and one subject can _have_ multiple students (think of a concrete example and you'll see it). So, N-N would require a third table (such as `student_subject`), which would have two foreign keys: the student id and the subject id. You can read more on database normalization and examples to try and understand it.

Comment: the table structure is not normalised it should be a many-to-many, you should have 3 tables, students and subjects, each subject row is a type like maths, english or whatnot. then you have a linking table which links students to subjects, then on delete you cascade, so the link is removed and the student. Else your have a ton of subject rows and need to add columns to add subjects, or go down the road of using CSV's as values. This is why I use an ORM so I don't have to think about it ;p